# How can a classless OOP language like TypeScript have static methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I'm really confused. If TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript and JavaScript is a classless language, then how can TypeScript have static methods?

As far as I understand, which could be wrong, in OOP languages supporting classes, a static method is part of the class which does not depend in any way on a particular instance of the class. A class is a piece of code, a blueprint, that contains enough information for cloning itself in the memory during runtime and a static method is part of that blueprint from the very beginning.

But JS does not support classes. Everything in JS is an object. So, there's no blueprint. There is something in memory that is replicated times and times again whenever we use the new keyword in JS/TS. So, the concept of the keyword static is very confusing to me in this case.

I would appreciate if someone clears up these concepts and how they are related to each other and why I'm wrong.

Comment: Wouldn’t the prototype be considered the “blueprint”?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Hmm. Good point. Now I'm even more confused. xD So, classless OOP and class-based OOP are pretty much the same? What about compiled languages? It seems to me that a class can exist independently during compile time but I'm not sure if that's the case for an object and its prototype property.

Comment: [Javascript supports classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: "But JS does not support classes." And yet... https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-class-definitions

Comment: @AndyRay Damn, I swear every single tutorial about JS on the internet mentions at some point that JS does not support classes and it's all syntactic sugar under the hood. :( I've lived a lie my whole career :(

Comment: They’re different, with overlap. Compilation isn’t really a gating issue, but I’m not sure what you were trying to say there.

Comment: @stressedout Define “supports classes”—how they’re implemented is different than whether or not they’re supported.

Comment: @stressedout "and it's all syntactic sugar" --- the "syntactic sugar" claim makes no sense in general: literally **everything** is a "syntactic sugar" over CPU instructions, yet we have beautiful higher level programming languages.

Comment: As others have said, JavaScript has classes. Importantly, TypeScript only has classes because JavaScript has them.

Comment: Before the `class` keyword, you could still program OOP by using `function Car()` and then doing `let car = new Car()`. But the `class` keyword makes it all a bit more readable / approachable. Also, don't forget that the internet is full of javascript tutorials that are literally DECADES old.

Comment: About static functions in classes, I have to say that since the introduction of `modules`, they seem a bit redundant. If all you want is a function that is not part of a class instance (so you can call the function directly without using `new`), you can just create a `module` that holds all those functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript and JavaScript is a classless language, then how can TypeScript have static methods?

JavaScript is not a classless language. [Here's the documentation on classes on JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

You may be confused because JavaScript did not always have classes. But it turns out, you can emulate a class like system with the prototype based system pretty easily. So this difference doesn't really matter most of the time. Even before official support for classes was added, you could still easily have what most would consider a "static method".

But all modern JavaScript engines support the `class` keyword for traditional `OOP` styles.

> In OOP languages supporting classes, a static method is part of the class which does not depend in any way on a particular instance of the class.

Correct.

> A class is a piece of code, a blueprint, that contains enough information for cloning itself in the memory during runtime and a static method is part of that blueprint from the very beginning.

It actually not part of that blueprint at all. It's part of the *factory* that produces that blueprint. So it belongs to the *constructor*, not the instances. An instance does not have direct access to static method.

If you had a class named `Person` and a static method to find all person records from a database, then a single `Person` instance would never need to find all the people from the database. That belongs to the concept that is the *collection* all `Person`s and not any instance.

So static methods aren't part of the blue print because they are not part of what the instance has to work with.

---

It's simpler than you think. A `class` is a constructor of object that all have similar interface and behave a certain way. A `static` member of that class is simply a value that belongs to that constructor and never belongs to instances.

This is a static method named `findAll`:

```
class Person {
  static async findAll(): Promise<Person[]> { ... }
  instanceMethod() { ... }
}

const people = await Person.findAll()
new Person().instanceMethod
```

And so is this: *(although this is much hard for poor TypeScript)*

```
function Person() {
  return this.name = 'Foo'
}
Person.prototype.instanceMethod = () => { ... }
Person.findAll = async (): Promise<Person[]> => { ... }

const people = await Person.findAll()
new Person().instanceMethod
```

In both cases here, there is a constructor that can produce instances which have an instance method. And that constructor also has a static method.

All that changes when you add the `static` keyword is that the method becomes available on the constructor, and is no longer available on instances.

Comment: "An instance does not have direct access to static method." Sorry for my ignorance, but I do not fully understand this part. For example, in PHP, I can use $this keyword to access a static method even in a non-static function. So, does this mean that the access here is indirect or via a proxy or what? Because you said an instance does not have direct access to static methods.

Comment: Class instances definitely do not have access to static properties on that class. See https://tsplay.dev/NaR0Em "So, does this mean that the access here is indirect or via a proxy or what?" there is no access, so no proxy, no magic. I can't speak for PHP, but this is how classes in JavaScript, and I believe _most_ OOP languages, work.

Comment: This seems specific to TypeScript, I guess. Look at this [PHP code](https://onlinephp.io?s=TY69CsMwDITnGPIOGgpJhpIHSH8ghY5dOwbHKLUhyMaW26H03SvTIQUJjjvp4w7nYEOtLqtOCa7ew7tWVcjz6gwsmQw7TzBNxlPimA23neTlpup7uHm2jh7giDFi4qKtKIk_shspseZ_4KjjBorIORI0d6sZnxib4fcvU6vdIp2OQPgq7dpOMjTWQ_H3p7lwBvgC&v=8.2.7), for example. I think it's probably the same in some other OOP languages I know as well, but I have to test it in Python, Java and C# before claiming so.

Comment: Do you consider `instance.constructor.staticProp` not to be "direct" access? TS doesn't strongly type `constructor` for [reasons](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) but it works in JS.

Comment: @stressedout I may be wrong this is how "most" OOP languages work. Java, for example does allow static methods to be referenced from the instances. http://tpcg.io/_PTHNLZ. But it is how _JavaScript_ works. @jcalz And yeah in typescript at least `(this.constructor as typeof Foo).staticMethod()` seems much worse than just `Foo.staticMethod()` so I didn't mention it at the risk it'd muddy the waters here. But it's good to acknowledge that exists, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how would `static` look in ES5, before 'class' and other cool features were introduced.

So you have some class (in ES5 that would be a function with accepting arguments like a constructor) e.g. named Person.

To add static method you would just assign some property to this class, so it will look like:

```
Person.getSpecies = function() { return 'Homo sapience' };
```

And this is it. `getSpecies` is a static method of a class `Person`. It's a standalone property of an object.

Using ESNext syntax it will look smth like:

```
class Person { static getSpecies() { return 'Homo sapience' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the things like `JS has classes since 2015` and others,

Everything in JS in an object.
A **Function** is also an object
So the function can have properties
And a "static" function is a property of the function itself rather then it's `prototype`

```
function foo(){}

foo.bar = 123 // "static" property of foo
foo.prototype.asd = 999 // prototype property of foo instance

let i = new foo();
i.asd // 999
i.constructor == foo // true
i.constructor.bar // 123
```